# firestore multiple where query for resource visibility and ownership

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I have a collection called Links. Each link can be private or public and only the signed in users can see the links. But only the owner or author of the links can see the private links.

This is the fetch data code I wrote:

```
const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    const links = [];
    firebase.collection('links').where("visibility","==","public").get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(link =>{
            let link_id = link.id
            let link_obj = { ...link.data(), ['id']: link_id}
            links.push(link_obj);
        })
        setLinks(links);
    })
}, [])
```

This here are the rules I have:

```
match /links/{link}{
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow read: if resource.data.visibility == 'public' || resource.data.created_by == request.auth.uid;
}
```

But as you can guess from my code I have no clue on

1. how to show the link to the owner himself. Since some links have
   been marked private not even the owner can see the links.
2. I need a more complex rule so that only if some one is logged in can see the public links, and the owners can see everything he submitted

**Update 1:** This is what I've tried so far. Making two different queries and then merging them together.

But the `query.then()` is throwing an error saying it's not a function.

When I comment out the lines and just `console.log(query)` I get this: `[object Promise][object Promise]`

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const links = [];
    
    const visibility_filter = firebase.collection('links').where("visibilty","==","public").get();
    const owner_filter = firebase.collection('links').where("created_by","==",currentUser.uid).get();

    const query = visibility_filter + owner_filter;
    console.log(query);
    query.then(snapshot=>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(link =>{
            let link_id = link.id
            let link_obj = { ...link.data(), ['id']: link_id}
            links.push(link_obj);
        })
        setLinks(links);
    })
}, [])
```

What am I missing out on?

Comment: I think you're looking for `query.get().then(...` or `query.onSnapshot(...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is the owner the author? If it is  you could use something like:

```
firebase.collection('links').where("created_by","==",ownerUid).get()
```

2. Try something like this:

```js
match /links/{link}{
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow read: if (resource.data.visibility == 'public' && request.auth.uid != null) || resource.data.created_by == request.auth.uid;
}
```

Comment: sorry for the poor choice of words. I shouldn't have used the "owner". But I meant the same thing by owner and author.

Your suggestion helps but other users can't see the public links now>

What I need is any logged In user can see the public links but only the author can see the links he made private

Comment: Hmm I haven't noticed that you want to get those in a single request to the database. That is not possible. If you make two request to the collection with those separate filters it will work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such filters?

Comment: Just make two separate requests like `firebase.collection('links').where("visibility","==","public").get()` and `firebase.collection('links').where("created_by","==",ownerUid).get()` and combine the results.

Comment: hi i tried what you suggested but still getting some errors

Comment: I've updated the rules as per your suggestion. Now in console I get `query.then()` is not a function. Am I combining the results correctly?

Comment: You can't combine them like this `const query = visibility_filter + owner_filter;` you need to work them trough like two separate queryies, loop over them and save the results to a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do an OR condition across multiple fields in Firestore queries.

With your current data model you'll have to execute two queries (one for the public documents, and one for the owned documents) and merge the results in your application code.

Both queries will be allowed, as the two sides of `||` clause in your security rules matches each of them.

Comment: I've updated my code with the suggestions but still getting an error